# Get SharePoint Access token from already generated access token for the Microsoft Graph resource (https://graph.microsoft.com)

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, adal

I am trying to get access token for SharePoint online site collection using already generated access token for Microsoft graph resource, and pass that access token to get client context of site collection using Pnp AuthManger.

Can anybody suggest me how this can be done? is it feasible or not?

I am aware about the fact one can make two different authentication call for different resource group.

Found below article, but it seams AuthenticationContext class in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory is updated and no longer have  AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenByRefreshTokenAsync method.

http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/08/getting-access-tokens-for-both-sharepoint-and-microsoft-graph/

Note: I am using .net libraries for above.

Answer (score 1):

ADAL supports acquiring tokens for multiple resources.You can still use ADAL library to achieve your requirement .

Yes , in ADAL 3, AcquireTokenByRefreshToken method doesn't exist .But refresh token is still present in the token cache , you don’t really ever need to use the refresh token from your own app code . With ADAL 3, when you want to get access token for different resource , you can use `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` method :

```
 string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
 AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
 ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
 result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(YourResource, credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
```

When calling that method , it will check the token cache . If it is a difference resource that no access token exists(or access token is expired)  , it will use refresh token(if exists and not expire) to get new access token for that resource .